# Keras LSTM-based neural network doesn't learn

Tags: python, keras, neural-network, lstm

I am very new to neural networks in general, and I'm trying to build a basic recurrent network for a student project.
So, here's my code:

```
import tensorflow
from tensorflow import keras
import numpy

X = numpy.zeros((21, 210, 3))

# Some code filling X from a file

Y = numpy.array([0,0,0,0,0,0, -1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1, 1,1,1,1,1,1])
Y = Y*0.5 + 0.5

model = keras.models.Sequential()
#model.add(keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=(210, 3)))   -commented out as it didn't make a difference
model.add(keras.layers.LSTM(32, input_shape=(210, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

model.summary()

model.compile(
  optimizer='adam',
  loss='categorical_crossentropy',
  metrics=['accuracy'],
)

model.fit(X, Y, epochs=5)
```

So, X is 21 "pages" of data with 3 features along 210 timesteps - which is how LSTM should expect it, and Y is an array of 21 values associated with each of the pages of X.
The network is supposed to learn to predict associated Y value based on a page of X.

The problem is that runnig the program speeds through the training and the accuracy stays constant (with some occasional, seemingly random spikes like 0.4286 shown below):

```
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
lstm (LSTM)                  (None, 32)                4608      
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, 1)                 33        
=================================================================
Total params: 4,641
Trainable params: 4,641
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
2021-07-07 14:41:56.530633: I tensorflow/compiler/mlir/mlir_graph_optimization_pass.cc:176] None of the MLIR Optimization Passes are enabled (registered 2)
Epoch 1/5
1/1 [==============================] - 1s 961ms/step - loss: 0.0000e+00 - accuracy: 0.2857
Epoch 2/5
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 39ms/step - loss: 0.0000e+00 - accuracy: 0.2857
Epoch 3/5
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 35ms/step - loss: 0.0000e+00 - accuracy: 0.2857
Epoch 4/5
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 36ms/step - loss: 0.0000e+00 - accuracy: 0.4286
Epoch 5/5
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 34ms/step - loss: 0.0000e+00 - accuracy: 0.2857

Process finished with exit code 0
```

What am I doing wrong? Again, it is all very new to me, so i assume it can be almost anything.
Thanks in advance

Comment: You cannot use categorical cross-entropy with a single binary output. Use `binary_crossentropy` instead.

Comment: I tried `binary_crossentropy` first (the issue was the same) and moved on later because the output isn't binary, has three distinct values that are present in the training data - 0, 0.5 and 1

Comment: What is 0.5 exactly? In classification your outputs should be discrete.

Comment: I have a label system going negative-neutral-positive. I tried doing labels -1, 0 and 1 to match that, but then switched to 0, 0.5 and 1 so that the output could be represented by a sigmoid that goes from 0 to 1. Is that wrong?